# PostgreSQL equivalent of custom PHP truncation email adress

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

I am looking for the faster/more efficient way to make the same truncation as

```
$tmp = explode(";", $d);
    foreach ($tmp as $key => $value) {
    $tmpp = explode("@", $value);
    $ext = explode(".", $tmpp[1]);
    $tmp[$key] = substr($tmpp[0], 0, 1)."[...]@".substr($ext[0], 0, 1)."[...].".end($ext);
}
return implode(", ", $tmp);
```

in PHP, but directly with PostgreSQL.

For example, the adresse "barnaby@free.fr" or "barnaby.lo@free.net.fr" should be "b[...]@f[...].fr"

Here is my solution, but probably not the best:

```
substr(emailn, 1, 1)||'[...]@'||substr(split_part(emailn, '@', 2), 1, 1)||'[...].'||split_part(split_part(emailn, '@', 2), '.', (length(split_part(emailn, '@', 2)) - length(replace(split_part(emailn, '@', 2),'.',''))) + 1) AS emailn
```

Comment: `select array_to_string(regexp_matches('barnaby.lo@free.net.fr', '^(.).*(@.).*(\..*)$'),'[...]');`

Comment: Awesome @Abelisto, it works, but sush a long time to complete the request !..

Comment: regular expressions is not a fastest way to deal with text. `select concat(substring(x,1,1),'[...]@',substring(x from '%@#"_#"%' for '#'),'[...]',substring(x from '%#".%#"' for '#')) from (values('barnaby.lo@free.net.fr')) t(x);` - could be faster.